# Emacs installed with the Ubuntu application manager runs but isn't in the $PATH. Where is it?

Tags: ubuntu, path

Emacs 26.2 is installed with the application manager, not apt-get.

When calling it in the terminal I get :

```
samusz@samusz-K55:~$ emacs

La commande « emacs » n'a pas été trouvée, mais peut être installée avec :

sudo apt install emacs25      
sudo apt install emacs25-nox  
sudo apt install e3           
sudo apt install emacs25-lucid
sudo apt install jove
```

(emacs command couldn't be found, but can be installed with...)

```
samusz@samusz-K55:~$ whereis emacs
emacs: /etc/emacs /usr/share/emacs
samusz@samusz-K55:~$ which emacs
samusz@samusz-K55:~$ ^C
samusz@samusz-K55:~$
```

there is no binary in /etc/emacs nor /usr/share/emacs, just config files !

So as a get-around I'll uninstall and get fresh binaries but I am interested as to what I do wrong. Or may be Ubuntu is not getting better if they can't configure the path when installing binaries.

I hate it when things get hidden away.

Is this a bug or a feature? (and if does it need reporting where ?)

(I was trying to get `pdf-tools` working when hit this wall)

Comment: If you think it is an Emacs bug, after checking comments and answers here, you can report it using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If you think it's a Ubuntu bug then consider reporting it to the Ubuntu developers.

Comment: Linux uses `$` to identify environment variables. The percent symbol `%` is a Windows convention. Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux? If so, you should state that in your question.

Comment: The binaries for anything installed with the Ubuntu package manager (which I'm pretty sure calls apt-get behind the scenes) should go into `/usr/bin`, or `/bin/`. It looks like your path is not set properly. It shouldn't include /etc/ or /usr/share, so whereis shouldn't report anything from those directories.

Comment: @nega Yes sorry I meant $PATH. Should I correct the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18.04, the `emacs` package is a meta-package. If we look at it's dependancies...

```
❯ apt-cache show emacs |grep Depends
Depends: emacs-gtk (>= 1:26.1) | emacs-lucid (>= 1:26.1) | emacs-nox (>= 1:26.1)
```

From the terminal we can find which dependency was installed...

```
❯ dpkg --get-selections |grep ^emacs
emacs                       install
emacs-bin-common            install
emacs-common                install
emacs-el                    install
emacs-gtk                   install
emacsen-common              install
```

In this case, you'll notice that of the three options, `emacs-gtk` was installed. We can then look at the contents of that package...

```
❯ dpkg -L emacs-gtk
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/emacs-gtk
/usr/share
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/emacs-term.desktop
/usr/share/applications/emacs.desktop
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/emacs
/usr/share/emacs/26.1
/usr/share/emacs/26.1/etc
/usr/share/emacs/26.1/etc/DOC
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/emacs-gtk
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/doc/emacs-gtk
/usr/share/man/man1/emacs-gtk.1.gz
```

You'll notice, that in `/usr/bin` the file `emacs-gtk` was installed.

You can find some other "emacs" stuff that might be installed in `/usr/bin/`

```
❯ ls -l /usr/bin/emacs*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       23 May  3 16:04 /usr/bin/emacs -> /etc/alternatives/emacs*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       29 May  3 16:04 /usr/bin/emacsclient -> /etc/alternatives/emacsclient*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    31272 Apr 10 16:53 /usr/bin/emacsclient.emacs*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39926024 Apr 10 16:53 /usr/bin/emacs-gtk*
```

Alternatively you can use the search facilities at https://packages.ubuntu.com/.

If you think that a package is broken, [file a bug with Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: Thank you for your extensive reply. I'll check my path. I had felt I didn't use apt-get to install emacs as I wanted 26.2 version and this question steamed from getting a clean slate before reinstalling emacs.